# fail to create embedded derby java

Tags: java, derby, embedding

I created a embedded derby in JDBC  mode but when I try to access it in java class it gives me error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to create database 'myDB', see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at embededderby.Main.createConnection(Main.java:42)
    at embededderby.Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

Comment: you have an example of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all,

### config your folder to create a Database with:

```
System.setProperty("derby.system.home", System.getProperty("user.home")
            + "/myDbFolder");
```

and then

### create your database with properties

driverClassName = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"

url="jdbc:derby:SolofutbolParaguayDB;create=true" //to create a new Db

### Example

```
 public HelloWorld() {

    try {
        setDBSystemDir();
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        String strUrl = "jdbc:derby:SolofutbolParaguay;create=true";

        try {
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(strUrl);
            System.out.println("connection created");
            createTable(dbConnection);
            insertRecord(dbConnection);
            listRecord(dbConnection);
            System.out.println("connection close");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setDBSystemDir() {
    // Decide on the db system directory: <userhome>/.addressbook/
    System.setProperty("derby.system.home", "/Users/myuser/futbol
```

Comment: Sorry I am new in JAVA DB so which schema I shoud select I mean APP or any other I am using netbeans 6.8

Comment: in My example, i am creating schema and call to him: SolofutbolParaguay.. the derby.system.home define the folder home of your database.

Comment: but when I create a schema manually suppose "create schema A" and add a table in it then run in execute command it works. but when I try to use it in java class it gives me error that                                                                                                                                            java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'A' does not exist at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source) at

Answer (score 2):

When it says "see the next exception for details", here's how to do that: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: what it means                                                                 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'A' does not exist
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)

Comment: Here's some info about schema names in Derby: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefschemaname.html and here's another good place to start: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html