# Spring,Hibernate with embedded derby- Jetty auto redeploy DB connection issue

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, derby, embedded-jetty

I am running a spring hibernate application with embedded derby Db and running it on jetty with auto redeploy. Now on doing an auto redeploy I get a DB connection error:

```
[INFO] restarting o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@2f7a6e0e{/,file:/D:/aa/branches/dev/saas/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:/D:/aa/branches/dev/saas/src/main/webapp/}
2016-05-10 11:57:40.932:INFO:/:Scanner-0: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
2016-05-10 11:57:40 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:862 - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue May 10 11:57:25 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-05-10 11:57:40.967:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Stopped o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@2f7a6e0e{/,file:/D:/aa/branches/dev/saas/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:/D:/aa/branches/dev/saas/src/main/webapp/}
[INFO] Webapp source directory = D:\aa\branches\dev\saas\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = D:\aa\branches\dev\saas\target\classes
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = D:\aa\branches\dev\saas\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:/D:/aa/branches/dev/saas/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = D:\aa\branches\dev\saas\src\main\webapp
2016-05-10 11:57:42.191:INFO:saas:Scanner-0: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2016-05-10 11:57:42.322:INFO:saas:Scanner-0: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
2016-05-10 11:57:42 INFO  DispatcherServlet:484 - FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
2016-05-10 11:57:42 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:510 - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue May 10 11:57:42 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-05-10 11:57:42 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
2016-05-10 11:57:42 INFO  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:172 - Loading properties file from class path resource [application.properties]
2016-05-10 11:57:42 INFO  AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:153 - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-05-10 11:57:42 INFO  MLog:92 - MLog clients using log4j logging.
2016-05-10 11:57:42 INFO  C3P0Registry:216 - Initializing c3p0-0.9.2.1 [built 20-March-2013 10:47:27 +0000; debug? true; trace: 10]
2016-05-10 11:57:42 INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-05-10 11:57:42 INFO  Version:54 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
2016-05-10 11:57:42 INFO  Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-05-10 11:57:42 INFO  Environment:346 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-05-10 11:57:42 INFO  AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:522 - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hge0ws9g16jrn8m15ijs29|2a8c236e, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge0ws9g16jrn8m15ijs29|2a8c236e, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:derby:aaSaas;create=true, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
2016-05-10 11:58:13 WARN  BasicResourcePool:1851 - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@53b953ec -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'aaSaas' with class loader WebAppClassLoader=saas@5fce839, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'aaSaas' with class loader WebAppClassLoader=saas@5fce839, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database D:\aa\branches\dev\saas\aaSaas.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
2016-05-10 11:58:13 WARN  BasicResourcePool:1851 - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@443e7c3e -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to create database 'aaSaas', see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
Caused by: ERROR XJ041: Failed to create database 'aaSaas', see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: ERROR XBM0J: Directory D:\aa\branches\dev\saas\aaSaas already exists.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService.createServiceRoot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
```

Now my question is how do I close the connection on redeploy so it can create a new one or can I use the same connection?

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service, 
        DAO -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.aa.saas" />

    <!-- Getting Database properties -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- View Resolver <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" /> <property name="suffix" 
        value=".jsp" /> </bean> -->

    <!-- DataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driverClass}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <!-- <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${connection.acquireIncrement}" 
            /> <property name="minPoolSize" value="${connection.minPoolSize}" /> <property 
            name="maxPoolSize" value="${connection.maxPoolSize}" /> <property name="maxIdleTime" 
            value="${connection.maxIdleTime}" /> -->
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.aa.saas"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="aaSaasUserDAO" class="com.aa.saas.aaSaasUserDAOImpl"></bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID">
    <display-name>saas</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**application.properties**

```
#Database related properties
database.driverClass=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
database.url=jdbc:derby:aaSaas;create=true
database.username=aa
database.password=aa

#Hibernate related properties
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true

#Connection pool related properties
#connection.acquireIncrement=2
#connection.minPoolSize=20
#connection.maxPoolSize=50
#connection.maxIdleTime=600
```

Comment: Please have a look at the below post for your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491328/stopping-tomcat-doesnt-delete-derby-db-lck

Comment: @shankarsh15 This is what they say: First the problem : when using Derby as an embedded database, the database is booted at first connection, but it has to be explicitely shutted down. If it is not, the db.lock file is not deleted and further application may experience problems booting the database again. Nothing exists either in tomcat or (by default) in spring to automatically shutdown such a database... But what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Harinder,

I think you need to edit some code.

Read Error Message..

1. Directory D:\aa\branches\dev\saas\aaSaas already exists.
2. Change the schema `<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">aaSaas</prop>`

delate folder in derby folder(aaSaas)

```
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">test</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">4</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.shutdown">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop><!--delete all entity after create entity  -->
        </props>
```

um...

dataSource

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource"> 
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"></property> 
    <property name="username" value="user"></property> <property name="password" 
    value="1234"></property> <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/aaSaas;create=true"></property> 
    </bean>
```

I use JPA and Derby..
In other cases.

um.. good luck

Comment: I have updated my question and have added the properties I am using. Tried changing the hbm2ddl to create also and it didn't work

Comment: you read  -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999106/fail-to-create-embedded-derby-java